# can i do process with form django python

Tags: python, django

there is a input and select with options in form tag. i want to get input value and option that entered. and i will do somethings on backend with python that value and option than i will return a result to website. but i dont use to forms.py. how can i do? is it possible?

```
<form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="text" name="getinputValue">
                    <select name="">
                        <option value="1"></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                      </select>
                    <button type=""class=""></button>
                    <p>{{result}}</p>
                </form>
```

Comment: did you have a model for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from what I understanding in your question, you want to retrieve the data from the form in your views and do something with it. You will have to give your `<select>` a name attribute so that you can reference it in your views.

```
<select name="level">
   <option value="1"></option>
   <option value="2"></option>
   <option value="3"></option>
</select>
```

In your views, one of the ways you can retrieve this data is by:

```
def options_view(request):
    level = request.POST.get('level') # get name of option as specified in the <select> tag
    # here you can do something with it
    print(level)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'level': level})
```

This is one way to do it.